# Calculate all possible integer powers of $z^{n}, n \in I$

Tags: complex-numbers

I saw a very interesting task to solve and got stuck. Does anyone has some hints how to solve this? Thank you very much in advance, further I wrote what I did. There is a complex number in its algebraic form: $$z=\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

---

I rewrote it in exponential form in order to raise it to the power ($ Arg(z) = arctan(\sqrt{3}) = \frac{\pi}{3}$): $$\frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4}}e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}$$
$$z^n = e^{in\frac{\pi}{3}}$$

---

Arg(z) is a tangent of Imaginary and Real part of the complex number and it could be rewritten like that: $$e^{i(n\frac{\pi}{3}+2n\pi k)}$$
How all integers powers could be determined here?

Comment: tell us what $z^2$   is. Then $z^3 .$  That should do it

Comment: $z^2 = e^{i(2\frac{\pi}{3})}$ and $z^3 =e^{i(3\frac{\pi}{3})} = e^{i\pi}$. So I have got a value without a frac but there is a $\pi$ still, so is it possible that it will be all values where $\pi$ will be canceled due to the $2\pi k$ period?

Comment: $ e^{i \pi}$  has a familiar expression.... If I just gave you a real number $t$  and demanded $e^{it},$ as real and imaginary parts, what would you say?

Comment: @WillJagy Yes! $\pi$ and $2\pi$ will be different in terms of the sign but they will repeat each time, i.e. $3\pi$ will give -1 and $4\pi$ will give 1 and so on, If I am right. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear that IF there is a power, $n>1$ where $z^n=1$, then any power after $n$ is guaranteed to be equal to one of the powers less than $n$ (i.e., $z^{n+m}=1\cdot z^m=z^m$). As such, it is reasonable to just perform powers until you reach $1$ (if that ever happens). I believe $z^6=1$ hence the only possible answers are $$z,z^2,z^3,z^4,z^5,z^6$$ and after that will always repeat.

Comment: So I tried to do raise $z$ to powers from $1$ to $6$ on the $z^3=e^{i\pi} = -1$ then $z^4=e^{i4\frac{\pi}{3}} = -\frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $z^5=e^{i5\frac{\pi}{3}} = \frac{1}{2} - i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $z^6=e^{i6\frac{\pi}{3}} = e^{i2\pi}= 1$, $z^7=e^{i7\frac{\pi}{3}} = \frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ - the same as $z^1$. Thank you very much!!